# Add non-duplicates to vector in R

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, duplicates, pipe

I'd like to check over vectors whether there are duplicates and only get the non-duplicates in a new vector in `R`.

Example: I've got four vectors to start with, let's say:

```
vec1<-c("C1")
vec2<-c("C1", "C4")
vec3<-c("C1", "C3")
vec4<-c("C2", "C3")
```

I want to check whether `vec1` and `vec2` combined have the same elements as `vec3` and `vec4` combined. The ones that are different from the ones in `vec3` and `vec4` I want to add to a new vector (in this case that would be only variable "C4").

The same I want to for `vec3` and `vec4`: the ones that are not in `vec1` and `vec2` I want to put in a new vector (in this case that would be variable "C2" and "C3").

Desired output:

```
vecnew1<-c("C4")
vecnew2<-c("C2, "C3")
```

Can I use `dplyr` or pipes for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not `dplyr`, but probably the simplest is to use `setdiff`:

```r
setdiff(c(vec1, vec2), c(vec3, vec4))
#[1] "C4"

setdiff(c(vec3, vec4), c(vec1, vec2))
#[1] "C3" "C2"
```

With pipes, that could work:

```r
c(vec1, vec2) |>
  setdiff(c(vec3, vec4))
#[1] "C4"
```

Comment: Only problem then is when all four vectors contain all the same elements (e.g.: they all only have "C1" as an element): then using setdiff would result in to "NULL" except I'd want "C1" as the output?